# AWS Cloudformation Random Build Fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using Cloudformation to automate instance creation. I'm using an auto scaling group to build a variable number dependent on what i need. However there is a reoccurring issue where at least 1 instance fails to run when i build 2+ instances from this script.

For Example: I state 7 instances for cloudformation to build, 6 will work perfectly but there is always 1 that will not work. There is no error, it just seems to ignore commands. In the userdata section of this script i launch dockers to run in the instance.

I get this error: `rpc error code = 13 desc = transport is closing`

Can someone take a look to see if doing something wrong or I'm missing a step?

```
     {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Test",
    "Parameters": {
        "InstanceType": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.large"
        },

        "NoOfInstances": {
            "Type": "String",
            "ConstraintDescription": ""
        },

        "RoleName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "**",
            "ConstraintDescription": ""
        },

        "VPCParameter": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Default": "**"
        },

        "SubnetsParameter": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Default": "**"
        },

        "KeyName": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "Default": "**",
            "ConstraintDescription": ""
        }
    },

    "Mappings": {
        "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
            "t2.large": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            }
        },

        "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
            "**": {
                "HVM64": "**"
            }
        }
    },

    "Resources": {

        "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "IamInstanceProfile": {
                    "Ref": "RoleName"
                },
                "SecurityGroups": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                }],
                "ImageId": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": ["AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                        {
                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                        }, {
                            "Fn::FindInMap": ["AWSInstanceType2Arch", {
                                "Ref": "InstanceType"
                            }, "Arch"]
                        }
                    ]
                },

                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": ["", [ ** ]]
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        "AutoScalingServerGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",

            "Properties": {
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
                },
                "MinSize": "1",
                "MaxSize": "30",
                "Cooldown": "300",
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
                    "Ref": "SubnetsParameter"
                },
                "DesiredCapacity": {
                    "Ref": "NoOfInstances"
                },
                "Tags": [ ** ]
            }
        },

        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "**",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPCParameter"
                },
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "CidrIp": "**",
                    "FromPort": "**",
                    "ToPort": "**"
                }, ]
            }
        },

        "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "AutoScalingServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
            }
        },

        "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "AutoScalingServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be hitting EC2 instance limits - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

You could also look at the *Activity History* tab for the Auto Scaling Group. See if it has any useful information.

Comment: I have Limits at a high capacity and activity history tab has no issues.